# ModuleNotFoundError Django views

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have created a separate module (sources.py) in my django project in order to hold functions and keep my views module from turning into a complete nightmare.

When I import sources.py into views.py, call the function it holds, and run the code, with a print statement to make sure what is called is accurately being imported, everything works fine and I see printed what I expect.

However, when I try to run the app in the local server I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

If I include the code from the function in views and then run the local server, everything works just fine.

The module obviously is being imported otherwise the print statement wouldn't work. However, something is lost when trying to run on the local server.

I have gone through a ton of stackoverflow questions, python and django module tutorials, and questions located elsewhere and nothing has seemed to solved the problem. Below is all the code.

sources.py and views.py are both in the same directory. (betrTV/betrTV_app/file.py)

I have also tried " `import sources *` with `original = sources.video()` which provided the same issue as well as `import . sources`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import date
from sources import video


''' returns a dict of unique video identifiers (last 11 chars)'''

original = video()
print(original)
sources = []


# strip out all except the unique source code
for i in range(len(original)):
    source = original[i]
    source = source[30:]
    sources.append(source)

# Checked out... print(sources)

# create day of week to pull video
day = date.today()
num = str(day)[9]

# pull source from list by using 'num' from 'day'
source = sources[int(num)]

def index(request):
    ''' The home page for betrTV_app '''

    video = 'class="video-frame" width="1200" height="600"\
        + src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/%s"\
        + frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; \
        + gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen' %source


    html = '<html><body><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi"\
        + rel="stylesheet"><h1 style="color: grey; font-family: Gugi; font-size: \
        + 20px;">BetrTV... Empowerment on Demand</h1>\
        <iframe %s></iframe></body></html>' %video

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

...

    # My Apps
    'betrTV_app',
]
```

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Prometheus\Dropbox\LVL6\Programming\Python\betrTV\betrTV\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
  path('', include('betrTV_app.urls')),
File "C:\Users\Prometheus\Envs\betr_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
  urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Users\Prometheus\Envs\betr_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Prometheus\Dropbox\LVL6\Programming\Python\betrTV\betrTV_app\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
  from . import views
File "C:\Users\Prometheus\Dropbox\LVL6\Programming\Python\betrTV\betrTV_app\views.py", line 4, in <module>
  from sources import video
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sources'
```

Comment: Where is `sources.py` located?

Comment: @Joseph.  sources.py is located in the same directory as views.py.